# What does Laurel Weaver like to do sometimes, when it's really late?

Tags: men-in-black

**From the Men in Black autopsy scene:**

*After a particularly gross GUSHY sound, he looks away, toward her.
She's staring at him.*

*Laurel leans over and lowers her voice, just for him.*

```
            LAUREL
    You know what I like to do sometimes? When
    it's really late?

            JAY
        (freaked out)
    No...
```

And, as far as I know, it's never mentioned again.  I'm curious if we know what it is she likes to do.

I've always assumed it was left intentionally unaddressed, because, well, that's funny.  But I could have missed something.  Plus there is the MIB comic.  Figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 7):

This scene is a comedic bit where the Laurel is referring to what she does *to the bodies at the autopsy*. The joke is that throughout the scene, Jay is constantly grossed out by what they are currently doing to the bodies (eg. sticking their hands inside a body's abdomen) and Laurel's comment implies she does far grosser things after hours. It is left unaddressed intentionally for the punchline as we can see Jay's reaction as he imagines what she could possibly be doing to the bodies (and at the same time leaving us viewers to imagine the same).